I get the error that a bean cannot be found and I don't know where the error is
I am learning Java spring boot and have programmed a basic REST API. Everything has worked so far. Since I have been in a VPN, the application no longer works. I get the following error message:
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.Registration required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.IUserRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.IUserRepository' in your configuration.

This cannot be due to the VPN. But I don't know what else it could be because everything looks right to me. Here is the program, with all files in one package, except the POM
class User:
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String prename;
    private String lastname;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private int age;
    
    public User() { }
    
    public User(String prename, String lastname, int age, String password, String email) {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.prename = prename;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.age = age;
    }
    
    //getter
    public String getID() {return id;}
    public String getPrename() { return prename;}
    public String getLastname() {return lastname;}
    public int getAge() {return age;}
    public String getEmail() {return email;}
    public String getPassword() {return password;}
    
    //setter
    public void setID(String id) {this.id = id;}
    public void setPrename(String prename) {this.prename = prename;}
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {this.lastname = lastname;}
    public void setAge(int age) {this.age = age;}
    public void setEmail(String email) {this.email = email;}
    public void setPassword(String password) {this.password = password;}
}

interface IUserRepository:
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface IUserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String>
{

}

class Registration (controller in short)
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

//import denniscompany.websitemodels.*;
//import denniscompany.websiterepositories.*;

@RestController
public class Registration {
    
    private IUserRepository userRepository;

    public Registration(IUserRepository p_oUserRepository ) {
        userRepository = p_oUserRepository;
        userRepository.save(new User("Test", "User", 28, "test@gmx.de", "1234"));
        
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public Iterable<User> getUsers() { return userRepository.findAll(); }
    

And my POM.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0-B01</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.224</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

In Eclipse I do not get an error message that it could not compile. So hopefully someone could help me.
I have tried these solutions on this linkCan't Autowire @Repository annotated interface in Spring Boot
but it doesn't work. I tried to Autowire my repository and set to my interface the the annotation Repository. Additional I set to my main the annotation EnableJpaRepositories. But it gives me the same error. All files are in one package, so I dont need a scanComponent or scanEntity etc. The solution of my link is 9 years old and probably outdated.
Update:
I get an error in eclipse and a solution to import my interface. But when I click on it nothing happens. Probably because I can't import it, because it is in the same package
